# Proving Similar Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm currently going through Harvard's Abstract Algebra using Michael Artin's book, and have no real way of verifying my proofs, and was hoping to make sure that my proof was right.

The question reads:

> Prove that the matrices $\textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
> a &0 \\ 
> 0 & d
> \end{bmatrix}$ and $ \textbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
> a &b \\ 
> 0 & d
> \end{bmatrix}$ ($b \neq 0$) are similar if and only if $ a \neq d$

My proof goes as follows:

We'll have to do this in two steps:

(1) **A** is similar to **B** $\rightarrow$ $a \neq d$
We'll do this by reductio and assume (i) **A** and **B** are similar and (ii) $a=d$. If that's the case, then we can write

$\begin{bmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$ as $\begin{bmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & a
\end{bmatrix}$ = a$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ = $aI.$

Then, by similarity we know

**B** = $PAP^{-1}$ = $PaIP^{-1}$ = $PaP^{-1}$ = $aPP^{-1}$ = $aI$.
This is a contradiction and therefore, we know that $a \neq d$

(2) $a \neq d$ $\rightarrow$ **A** and **B** are similar.

We can do this simply by choosing a $b$ and a $P$ to make this so. So choose $b = 1 - \frac{a}{d}$ and P = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{d} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$ Then,

$PAP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{d} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{-1}{d} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 \\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{-1}{d} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 - \frac{a}{d} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix} = \textbf{B}.$

As, this could work for all $b$ (as $b$ was chosen arbitrarily), this completes the proof.

Is this correct? Any and all feedback is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo where you say $a=b$. Presumably you meant $a=d$. With that correction, your proof that you must have $a \ne d$ is correct.

Comment: However, your logic for other direction is flawed. You can choose $P$ if you want, but you don't get to choose $b$. You have to work with arbitrary $a,b,d$, with $a \ne d$, regarded as unknown, but fixed.

Comment: If $a\neq d$, compute the eigenvector of $B$ corresponding to $d$ and put it in the second column of $P$. The first column has to be $(1,0)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your (2), you have to prove the statement for any $a,b,d$ with $a\neq d$ instead for a special $b.$ Hence you may first try some $P$ like what you did, so put 
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and hence 
$$PAP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & x(a-d) \\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then since $a\neq d,$ you can choose $x = \frac{b}{a-d}$ and get that $A$ and $B$ are similar by some invertible $P.$